# Exceptional Curves provided by Dominant Morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a dominant morphism between integral algebraic surfaces (so a $2$-dimensional, proper $k$-scheme).

I know that there I exist a open set $V \subset Y$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $f \vert _{f^{-1}(V)} \to V$ is a isomorphism.

Futhermore, if $Y$ is also normal $V$ can be choosen as $V := Y \backslash \{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ where $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ is a finite set of closed points.

$E_i := f^{-1}(x_i)$ are called ***exceptional curves***. If $Y= Spec(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)$ then it can be showed that $E_i$ are connected.

But why they are ***curves*** (= $1$-dimensional, proper $k$-scheme) and not points?

Comment: First, you don't say $f$ is birational, without which the second line is false (unless $V$ is allowed to be empty. The quickest proof for what you need is using Zariski's main Theorem.

Comment: Consider the largest open set $U$ of $Y$ such that the for all $u \in U$, the fiber $f^{-1}(u)$ are points. Then $f|_{f^{-1}(U)}$ will be a quasi-finite map. Now use this(Thm 8.5 from http://math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/ZMTfull.pdf ) version of ZMT to say that $f|_{f^{-1}(U)}$, will be an isomorphism since $Y$ is normal.